# .htaccess rewrite, trying to remove .html file extension on all files EXCEPT index file

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a "simple" rewrite for all of my files so that you don't have to go to a link with .html at the end of the url. I've got a code that works almost completely, except for the fact that it's rewriting ALL of the files, which then screws up my index.html file and that's kind of a big problem. This is the code that I'm using:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

I guess I just need a code in there that makes it ignore index.html, so I tried this, which gave me error 403 on my index page and error 500s on every other page:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html$ $0 [L]
```

But I guess in the end, I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing and I don't know where to put the line of code, and I don't know if it's even entirely correct.

The ORIGINAL code that I tried was this but that gave me error 403s on every page:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^((?!index).+?)/?$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Didn't work. It kept my index.html file intact, but I got error 500s with the rest. Also it messed up my css a bit.

Comment: What was the URL you tired to test this? Also for 500 you should check `Apache error.log` file.

Comment: I don't have a test site, I'm doing this straight on the live site unfortunately. www.timbertechstairs.com  Also I'm not sure how to check the Apache error.log file, especially since I'm not actually running Apache on my computer. The site is being hosted through our internet provider (who DOES run apache), so I'm not sure if I even have the option of checking the apache error.log file?

Comment: Usually through cpanel you get to check Apache's error.log but which URL is causing 500 on `www.timbertechstairs.com`?

Comment: I just retested this posted code and it worked fine.

Comment: Sorry I guess that was my bad, I didn't get error 500s on the other pages, they were just error 403s whoops. These are screenshots with the code that you suggested in place: [Index page that works](http://gyazo.com/feb8c20e3a1fbf058fe56cfa395eee27.png), and [Other pages that get error 403s](http://gyazo.com/49d205bf036aae0834ca375bf9c81713.png)

Comment: See updated code. Remember if `/products.html` doesn't exist then above rule won't be fired.

Comment: /products.html definitely exists. I tried your updated code and the index page shows up like I want it to, but for the rest I get error 403s

Maybe it's something that actually has to do with the way that my files are organized? I have my products.html file in the same directory as index.html, about.html, etc but because I have an actual FOLDER called "products" that I have other files in--maybe that's causing a conflict because it starts to auto look for that folder? That could explain why my products page isn't working, but that doesn't explain why my index page isn't working.

Comment: ^ I edited my comment above to maybe explain why products.html isn't working with my code. That being said, the update that you just posted still gives me 403s on every page except for index. :(

Comment: Is this .htaccess placed in `DOCUMENT_ROOT`?

Comment: Also are there more rules in this .htaccess? If yes then can you place content of .htaccess in question or on pastebin?

Comment: There are no more rules in the .htaccess file. The only text is what I've given you.  Also I don't know how to tell if it's placed in 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' or not. [This is a screenshot of where my htaccess file is saved in the /public/ folder](http://gyazo.com/ceafdf758d396b3cee3ec5637a8f4701.png)

Comment: Unfortunately that new code doesn't work either. :( index.html works, but /products.html gets error 403 and /products/commercial gets error 404

Comment: This is fully tested rule. It seems your .htaccess isn't even being read. Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: I am 100% sure that my code is being read seeing as the code that I originally used (in my question) was mostly working, except for the issues that I was having with only the index page not working. I've put code in there before and I have generated error 500s. Like I said, the only problem that I was having was that I was getting errors on my index file. :(